# Plain Spring @Async @Transactionl with database lock

Tags: java, spring, database, asynchronous, transactions

Please let me know what is the best way to do it. The case is as follows: I need to upload an excel file, parse it based on the data in it, make a call to an external service, and then aggregate all the information and put it into tables in the database. The method will be called asynchronously in order to release the frontend, a quick response is not needed, but there is a problem. At the time of data processing, I cannot allow anyone to write to certain tables in the database, that is, if the client wants to send the same file again until it has been processed, I cannot allow this. The problem is exacerbated by the fact that I have several servers running outside the cluster, but with a common database. Accordingly, I need to do synchronization through the database. What is the best way to do this? So far, I have not come up with anything better than to make a separate transactional method. Anyone have any ideas?

Comment: Some DBMS's allow you to execute a statement like, `LOCK TABLE some_table`.   I don't know what you're using, but you could look into whether it supports lock and unlock.  In a clustered app, you're going to want something simple like this